# sfdx force:auth:web:login – how to get it to work under Linux Mint?

Tags: salesforcedx, oauth2, authentication, oauth, auth

Can't connect any org under **Linux Mint** via `sfdx force:auth:web:login` 
Neither via `sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com -a foo` 
nor `sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://foo.my.salesforce.com -a foo` 
nor `sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://cs100.salesforce.com -a foo` 
Browser opens --> username/pw --> *…foo.my.salesforce.com/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp …* 
I'm redirected to the **RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage** and there I'm stuck in a white screen. 
On refresh **Firefox** gives me: 
**OAUTH_APPROVAL_ERROR_GENERIC : An unexpected error has occured during authentication. Please try again.** 
And **Brave**: 
**localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE** 

Same command on **Mac OS** works without any issues, org authenticated after seconds. 
So I think it is an issue on the Linux machine.

This is what I've tried already:

- turned off firewall on device
- changed default browser
- cleared browser chach
- disabled pihole dns server
- connected via different network (mobile)
- tried test.salesforce, cs100.salesforce, mydomain.salesforce


  The org I'm trying to connect right now is a **Sandbox**. But same behaviour with dev or prod. 
  There I've used a workaround via `sfdx force:auth:device:login` – but https://login.salesforce.com/setup/connect isn't working with a sandbox and neither is https://test.salesforce.com/setup/connect. 

  Port **1717** seams to open up correctly on the command:

```sh
$ netstat -tulpn
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 xxx.x.x.x:1717          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11880/node
```

Any ideas what the problem is and how to overcome it?

Comment: what is your sfdx version ?

Comment: sfdx-cli/7.84.2-a2868a68d5 linux-x64 node-v12.18.3

Comment: @Badbaxx I've updated **auth** with `sfdx plugins:install auth@latest` it on **v1.4.7**.

Comment: It could be related to that case : https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/767

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to downgrade, was running into an other error there. I've tried login via myDomain and device code without success. My setup was maybe special, dev org created from isv instance .. wasn't trying to hard to fix this as it was for personal testing only.

Anyway, I've just updated my Salesforce CLI to version **7.91.0-6a6ed69ebe** – and everything is working as expected again.

So if anyone runs into the same issue again and is under version 7.91, I recommend an upgrade instead of a downgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use OP's workaround in a Sandbox with the `instanceurl` option:

```
sfdx force:auth:device:login --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
```

I also used a "my" domain successfully.